# JHipster with JWT and OAuth2

Tags: jhipster

In jhipster is it possible to use facebook's JWT and OAuth2 in the same application? I already configured the application.yml and I added the @ EnableOAuth2Sso annotation in the SecurityConfiguration file, but I don't know how to create a token and a user in the application.

- Spring Boot 2
- Angular 6

Comment: If you are using JHipster's OAuth2 authentication type, you can set up social login in Keycloak or Okta: https://www.jhipster.tech/tips/024_tip_enabling_social_login_with_oauth2.html

Comment: So I'm using Hipster's JWT authentication type. Because I'd like to create user too. Is it possible using that model? Or aplication is only JWT or OAuth2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TLDR:** To the best of my knowledge, Jhipster offers only either of those.

Reasoning:

1. On the initial questions, you can only choose one.
2. They occupy the same field in the `.yo-rc.json` file (the `"authenticationType"` field)
3. In the docs ([here](https://www.jhipster.tech/security/)) they are presented as alternatives, with different attributes (stateful vs. stateless, etc.)

After all that, you can probably mix-and-match features from both (such as in [this](https://medium.com/@vdelacou/setup-jhipster-api-with-auth0-authentication-and-authorization-49cc2eca59c4) and [this](https://auth0.com/blog/quicktip-use-jhipster/) blog), but you have to implement it yourself.

Following all this, if anyone actually knows differently please correct me.